# Why does GNU Screen's "-X stuff" stop working after 84 lines?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

Edit: it's probably a bug (that it doesn't print any error and return 0), i have notified screen-devel gnu.org about the issue.

This script works fine:

```
screen -S foo -dm
sleep 1 # workaround https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?54164
screen -S foo -X stuff '
echo 0;
echo 1;
echo 2;
echo 3;
echo 4;
echo 5;
echo 6;
echo 7;
echo 8;
echo 9;
echo 10;
echo 11;
echo 12;
echo 13;
echo 14;
echo 15;
echo 16;
echo 17;
echo 18;
echo 19;
echo 20;
echo 21;
echo 22;
echo 23;
echo 24;
echo 25;
echo 26;
echo 27;
echo 28;
echo 29;
echo 30;
echo 31;
echo 32;
echo 33;
echo 34;
echo 35;
echo 36;
echo 37;
echo 38;
echo 39;
echo 40;
echo 41;
echo 42;
echo 43;
echo 44;
echo 45;
echo 46;
echo 47;
echo 48;
echo 49;
echo 50;
echo 51;
echo 52;
echo 53;
echo 54;
echo 55;
echo 56;
echo 57;
echo 58;
echo 59;
echo 60;
echo 61;
echo 62;
echo 63;
echo 64;
echo 65;
echo 66;
echo 67;
echo 68;
echo 69;
echo 70;
echo 71;
echo 72;
echo 73;
echo 74;
echo 75;
echo 76;
echo 77;
echo 78;
echo 79;
echo 80;
echo 81;
echo 82;
echo 83;
echo 84;
'
#85+ is broken..
#84 works
echo $?
```

and `echo $?` returns 0 meaning success.. However, if we add `echo 85;` to the list, it's like the whole screen -X stuff invocation is *completely* ignored! nothing actually happens in the foo screen, and there is no errors printed anywhere, and `echo $?` still prints 0 meaning success! what is going on? fwiw the original script where i encountered the issue was much smaller, this invocation works until you add 10gb_8:

```
screen -S emergency_diskspace -dm
sleep 1 # workaround https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?54164
screen -S emergency_diskspace -X stuff '
mkdir /emergency_diskspace;
cd emergency_diskspace;
dd if=/dev/urandom of=10gb_0 bs=10M count=1000 iflag=fullblock status=progress;
dd if=/dev/urandom of=10gb_1 bs=10M count=1000 iflag=fullblock status=progress;
dd if=/dev/urandom of=10gb_2 bs=10M count=1000 iflag=fullblock status=progress;
dd if=/dev/urandom of=10gb_3 bs=10M count=1000 iflag=fullblock status=progress;
dd if=/dev/urandom of=10gb_4 bs=10M count=1000 iflag=fullblock status=progress;
dd if=/dev/urandom of=10gb_5 bs=10M count=1000 iflag=fullblock status=progress;
dd if=/dev/urandom of=10gb_6 bs=10M count=1000 iflag=fullblock status=progress;
dd if=/dev/urandom of=10gb_7 bs=10M count=1000 iflag=fullblock status=progress;
'
```

observed on:

- Ubuntu 22.04 amd64
- kernel 5.15.0-40-generic
- GNU Screen version 4.09.00 (GNU) 30-Jan-22
- GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: I'm guessing there's a limit to the length of what you can put in the quotes. I doubt you're hitting the system's argument length limit, but you might be hitting screen's.

Comment: @barrycarter agreed, that seems likely. also it feels like a bug that screen doesn't print any error to stderr, and returns 0. and indeed i am not even CLOSE to hitting the OS max argument limit

Comment: OK, I just tried something like this and got `Remote command too long.` on the message line. Googling that (in quotes) shows others having the same issue. Testing, I found 500 is the limit (500 characters works, 501 doesn't). The weird thing is crossing from 84 to 85 in your script doesn't appear to cross the 500 character limit, since, even with 84, it's over 700 characters.

Comment: @barrycarter hmm maybe there is a bug like ```if you go too far above the 500 limit, like, 750ish, the 'remote command too long.' message doesn't appear```

Comment: I tried 1024 and still got the error message, but I'm doing `screen -X stuff \`perl -e 'print "x"x1024;'\`` directly and not nesting it inside another screen command. It's possible you're losing the error message due to "recursion"